# How to understand the defer statement

Tags: go

I have two examples about defer statement in golang, the first one is incorrect, and the second one is correct. But I think they have the same problem, in my opinion I think the second still has risk that run out of file descriptors, could any one can help me to clarify why the second is correct? Thanks!

Example1:

```
for _, filename := range filenames {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close() // NOTE: risky; could run out of file descriptors
    // ...process f...
 }
```

Example2:

```
for _, filename := range filenames {
    if err := doFile(filename); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
func doFile(filename string) error {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // ...process f...
}
```

Comment: Example 1 keeps all file descriptors open until the end and then closes all of them. Example 2 opens one file descriptor and closes it once done, so that in example 2 only one file descriptor is in use at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deferred functions run when the enclosing function returns. [Spec: Defer statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)

> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the surrounding function executed a [return statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements), reached the end of its [function body](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations), or because the corresponding goroutine is [panicking](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics).

In your first example you use a single `for` loop in which you use `defer` statements, but the deferred functions will not get executed at the end of the iterations, only after the `for` loop (when the enclosing function ends). This means all the files you open inside the `for` loop will remain open 'till the "end". If `filenames` contains a thousand valid file names, the loop will (try to) open a thousand files before starting to close any of them.

In your second example you "outsourced" dealing with the files to a separate function. Using `defer` in this function is fundamentally different, as when this function returns, the deferred function (`File.Close()`) will be called first. So in your second example at most 1 file is open at all times by the posted code, no matter how many elements `filenames` contains.